# How do I get the sizeof(T) safely in boost if T can be void?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I'm trying to figure our how I can get some code to compile that will determine the size of T's return value, where T is a function prototype, in my function template.

```
template<typename T>
void functionReturnLength()
{
long lReturnTypeSize = boost::mpl::eval_if<
    boost::is_void<boost::function_types::result_type<T>::type>::value, 
    boost::mpl::long_<0>,
    boost::mpl::long_<boost::mpl::sizeof_<boost::function_types::result_type<T>::type>::value>>::value;
}
```

However it still does not compile because sizeof(void) is not a valid operation - even though I am trying to construct an if-statement that will return a size of 0 if the type is void. I'm fairly new to BOOST MPL, so, while I have been browsing the documentation for some time, I am not sure how I could apply other ifs like if_ or apply_if, and if these would even work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use your own metafunction

```
template<typename T>
struct get_size { static const size_t value = sizeof(T); };

template<>
struct get_size<void> { static const size_t value = 0; };
```

Comment: Better yet, he could say `value = void_has_no_size()`, which will make the compiler complain that there's no such function as `void_has_no_size()`.

Comment: @Paul Manta: The OP's desire is to get 0 for void.

Comment: @curiousguy Obviously. But in some cases that's a desirable thing.

Comment: @PaulManta what is the point of a program that you cannot compile?

Comment: @curiousguy When you know your template will not function correctly with a certain type, you make it so that you cannot compile that specific type.

Comment: @curiousguy:  Consider `static_assert`

Comment: @JohnDibling what is the point of a program that cannot, ever, compile?

Comment: @JohnDibling re: first Paul Manta's comment

Comment: sizeof(void)=0 is the desired effect, as the type size corresponds to a type classification (i.e is it primitive or not) the size isn't supposed to be checked if the type is primitive and of type void, however the code must compile one way or another and it makes more sense to return 0 as sizeof(void). While I am aware that this is not portable, it is used internally enough to have little effect. Thanks Abyx, I don't know why I didn't think of doing that xd. I supposed I was too fixed on using boost, lol. I think I'm going to leave it open for another day to see if can get a mthod using boost.

Comment: @curiousguy: But, unless I misunderstood, that was a suggestion in the context of how to make a `static_assert`-type function fail when passed `void`.

Comment: @PaulManta `sizeof (T)` will make the code compilable when `T` is an object type and uncompilable when `T` is `void`. Calling an undeclared function `void_has_no_size()` will make the code uncompilable, always.

Comment: @user1070878 The discussion has drifted a little. There is a sub-thread here.

Comment: @curiousguy:  I don't understand.  The code suggested by PaulManta won't **always** fail to compile -- it will only fail to compile when it's passed a `void` template parameter.

Comment: @curiousguy:  Since it was PaulManta's suggestion, I'll let him elaborate.

Comment: @JohnDibling I guess something like `template<> struct get_size<void> { static const size_t value = void_has_no_size(); };` which cannot compile.

Comment: @curiousguy I meant to use the non-existent function only in the appropriate template specialization. Here it's moot since `sizeof(void)` doesn't compile anyway, but this (calling non-existent functions) is a common practice to forbid certain types in templates.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not going to go look for code... If you're _curious_ (ha! get it? :P ), go look into Boost. I _think_ I've seen this used there as well.

Comment: @PaulManta I _know_ that Boost is not going to call undeclared function any time soon.

Comment: "_but this (calling non-existent functions) is a common practice to forbid certain types in templates_" BTW, `get_size<void>` is not a template - it's a class template explicit specialisation.

Comment: @curiousguy, please see `boost::noncopyable` or `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` - they prevents compilation and use identifier with some meaningful name to produce readable error. And please stop add comments here, create new question, or chat room.

Comment: "_create new question_" But I don't have a question. This is **really** a trivial matter. I wanted to see the proof for some comments, and I now have my answer: the proof does not exist, the comments are wrong, end of story. (And please do not tell me to not add comments in reply to incorrect and misleading comments.)

Comment: Sorry all, but @curiousguy is right here. If you replace the `0` in the explicit specialization for `void` with `void_has_no_size()`, the code won't ever compile until the function is **both** a `constexpr` (only doable in C++11) and defined with a return value, at which point it will *always* compile. Stuff in explicit specializations can be looked up in the first phase of template lookup. Only nested, templated stuff can be deferred to phase two of the lookup (or function templates). See [here](http://ideone.com/0aDej) for a simple example of how to achieve what you tried with the function.